# Setting lots of properties to one object, then changing that object to update the properties

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I want to be able to set a lot of properties with only one object. For example, let's say I have a bunch of `UIButton`s, and I want to change their background color.
I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
UIColor *startColor= [UIColor blackColor];

btnA.backgroundColor = startColor;
btnB.backgroundColor = startColor;
btnC.backgroundColor = startColor;
```

Then in another method somewhere:

```
startColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This would change all of the button backgrounds to green.
I know that the `setBackgroundColor:` method copies the `UIColor`, so changing it this way isn't possible.

How would one go about doing this? You'd need some kind of (double) pointer. Would you have to implement your own class? Or this there already a way to do this? I should mention that I come from a C++ background.

Comment: You could use Key-Value Observation on startColor, so when it changes you can then update all the associated buttons you want, and wrap this all up in your own class.

Comment: Look into appearance proxies.

Comment: @CrimsonChris That helped a TON! I actually got it working without needing to assign a single button a color value! Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: Glad it helped. Why create some hack when Apple provides the functionality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in this specific case, because `UIColor` object is *immutable*.

Objective-C lets you share objects in the same way that C and C++ let you share objects - through pointers. When multiple objects reference a mutable object, and the object changes, all referencing objects can see this change at once. An immutable object cannot change, so the only way to change what some object "sees" is by setting a replacement object (i.e. a new color).

Mutable objects, on the other hand, let you keep changing the object outside, and have the changes become "visible" in them automatically. Consider this example:

```
@interface Demo
// Note: NSString properties are often marked as "copy" in production code
// in order to avoid the behavior that this code demonstrates.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;
-(void)show;
@end
@implementation Demo
-(void)show {
    NSLog(@"%@", _name);
}
@end
...
Demo *one = [[Demo alloc] init];
Demo *two = [[Demo alloc] init];
Demo *three = [[Demo alloc] init];
NSMutableString *commonName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello"];
pne.name = two.name = three.name = commonName;
// Now the name is shared
[one show];
[two show];
[three show];
[commonName appendFormat:@", world!"];
[one show];
[two show];
[three show];
```

The initial three calls to `show` produce three `hello`s; the last three calls produce three `hello, world!`s.

Comment: Side note - this code would also make a good demonstration of why it is common to define `NSString` properties with `copy` - to avoid this kind of side effect.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the comment - I edited to make this note. By the way, I noticed that Apple toke note, and made it much harder to make the same mistake in switft.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this helped a lot. Gives me a deeper understanding of obj-c.